# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') but there are no nan or infinite values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

This is the error that appears when I run my code for logistic regression using scikit library.

I have tried removing nan and infinite values but its not working

```
    df=pd.read_csv("bots.csv")
    df1=pd.read_csv("genuine.csv")

    df1.head

    np.where(df.values >= np.finfo(np.float64).max)
    np.where(df1.values >= np.finfo(np.float64).max)

    np.any(np.isnan(df))
    np.any(np.isnan(df1))

    np.all(np.isfinite(df))
    np.all(np.isfinite(df1))

    df1=df1[:-92]  #drop from bottom

    f_to_f_human=df['friend_to_folowers_ratio']
    f_to_f_bot=df1['friend_to_folowers_ratio']

    df1['Y']= 1 #1 for bot
    df['Y'] = 0 # 0 for human

    vx=df['Y']
    vy=df1['Y']

    A = pd.concat([df1, df])
    A

    y=A.iloc[:,-1].values
    X=A.drop(['Y'], axis=1)
    X=A.iloc[:].values
```

```
    X_train,X_test,y_train, y_test= 
    train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

    model=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=1)
    print(X_train)
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I am not expecting any error but error appears

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

​

Comment: You have `A = pd.concat([df1, df])`.  `A` is the dataframe that must be checked for `nan` or `NA`.  If I recall correctly, concatenating two dataframes can result in `NA` values because Pandas aligns the data using common index values.

Comment: I think that is the issue you mentioned but concat didn't create any NA values.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `X_train.isnull().sum()` return?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this one to your code:

```
    A = pd.concat([df1, df])
    A.dropna(inplace=True)

    y=A.iloc[:,-1].values
    X=A.drop(['Y'], axis=1)
    X=A.iloc[:].values

    X_train,X_test,y_train, y_test= 
    train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)

    model=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=1)
    print(X_train)
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

**A.dropna(inplace=True)** should drop all your NaN values

and another hint would be:
`A.dtypes`do check which format does your columns have